# Angular 2 / Ionic 2 application how to set preselected value on select input

Tags: angular, ionic2

I have the problem that I need to use modeldriven approach for forms in one of my apps. Now values get passed from the previous screen with the navController in Ionic. Problem is that it doesn't preselect the value that I pass.

Here is my code:

```
  /**
   * Initialize the form with value
   * @param email
   */
  initForm(data: any) {
    this._telefonArten = this._addressService.getKommunikationsArt('telefon');
        let transformedTelefonArten = new KeysPipe().transform(this._telefonArten, []);
        let artIndex = transformedTelefonArten.findIndex((element)=> {return element.key === data.art});
        this._telefonForm = this._formBuilder.group({
          'telefon': this._formBuilder.group({
            'nummer': [data.nummer, [Validators.required]],
            'art': [transformedTelefonArten[artIndex], []]
          })
        });
      }
```

Can anybody help?

Thanks,
Sebastian

Comment: I don't use Ionic. But you can say more on what is the problem then maybe non-ionic people can also help you.

Comment: check this out,  https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/ion-select-with-dynamic-options/43720/8 :)

Comment: It is more an Angular 2 problem. Cause we don't use the ion-select to get the touch and feel of native component. What I do is trying to set the value when the form group gets defined. But it always set itself to the first option of the select.